# Fragment inside of a DialogFragment c# android

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having some issues with adding a fragment (which will hold a google map) inside of my DialogFragment. Inside of my DialogFragment I have a FrameLayout set up like this

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The C# code that is setting up the DialogFragment and is trying to add the map is. Also I has specified IOnMapReadyCallback with the class.

```
         using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using System;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;

namespace My_Town_App.Droid
{
    class dialog_preview_busn : DialogFragment
    {
        public string gName, gAddress, gNumber, gEmail, gWebsite, gHours, gImage;
        public int gZip;
        private GoogleMap gMap;

        public dialog_preview_busn(string Name, string Address, int Zip, string Number, string Email, string Website, string Hours, string Image)
        {
            gName = Name;
            gAddress = Address;
            gZip = Zip;
            gNumber = Number;
            gEmail = Email;
            gWebsite = Website;
            gHours = Hours;
            gImage = Image;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("-----------------");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("dialog_preview_busn");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("-----------------");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Name: " + Name + "   Address: " + Address + "    Zip: " + Zip + "    Number: " + Number);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Email: " + Email + "    Website: " + Website + "    Hours: " + Hours + "    Image: " + Image);
            //gOnLogInComplete.Invoke(this, new OnLogInEventArgs(gtxtEmail.Text, gtxtPassword.Text));
            //PassedParams.Invoke(this, new PassedParams(user, pass));
        }

        //----------------------------------------
        // OnCreate Activity
        //----------------------------------------
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //Set the Title Bar to invisable
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            TextView txtName = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
            TextView txtAdress = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAddress);
            TextView txtNumber = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNumber);
            TextView txtEmail = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            TextView txtWebsite = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtWebsite);
            TextView txtHours = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHours);
            TextView labHours = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labHours);
            ImageView downArrow = View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.downArrow);
            LinearLayout mapLayout = View.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mapLayout);

            mapLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            SetUpMap();
            downArrow.Click += delegate
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("down arrow is working");
                if (mapLayout.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
                {
                    downArrow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.menu_down_arrow);
                    mapLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
                else if (mapLayout.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
                {
                    downArrow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.menu_up_arrow);
                    mapLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }

            };

            txtName.Text = gName;
            txtName.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.UnderlineText;

            txtAdress.Text = (gAddress + " " + gZip).ToString();
            txtNumber.Text = gNumber;
            txtEmail.Text = gEmail;
            txtWebsite.Text = gWebsite;
            string[] aryHours = gHours.Split(',');
            foreach (string s in aryHours)
            {
                txtHours.Text += (s + " ").ToString();
            }
            labHours.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.UnderlineText;

            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation; //set the animation
        }

        //----------------------------------------
        // OnCreate View
        //----------------------------------------

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_preview_busn, container, false);
            return view;

        }

        private void SetUpMap()
        {
            if (gMap == null)
            {
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.fragment);
            }


            LatLng location = new LatLng(50.897778, 3.013333);
            CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
            builder.Target(location);
            builder.Zoom(18);
            builder.Bearing(155);
            builder.Tilt(65);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.fragment);
            GoogleMap map = mapFrag.Map;

            if (map != null)
            {
                map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
        }        

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            gMap = googleMap;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function 'SetUpMap' should be async.
When is your function 'OnMapReady' been called? Have you connected it to an event? 
As far as the event is being fired you have to reload the layout.

Comment: Hey Kahlei thank you for the help here is my complete Fragment file that I am trying to use. Also the event that is showing the dialogFragment is on itemlongclick for a listview item